# How to print specific page of each of several PDFs in a folder

Tags: pdf, batch, printing

I have to print the second page of *several* PDFs. They are all on the same networked hard drive, but it's bogging down everything so badly. I was hoping there would be a way to accomplish this, perhaps with a batch file. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In word, learn how to create a macro. Have the macro go to file, print, add 2 on the 'print page number' box, print - then close document.

To make things easier - if your computer can cope - open all the documents up at the same time in word first, letting the macro print and then close each document for you.

Copy all the documents to either the local hard drive or a USB hard drive first to not clog up the network.